# Proving the Continuation Passing Style Monad in Coq

Tags: monads, coq, continuation-passing

I'm trying to prove the Monad laws (left and right unit + associativity) for the Continuation Passing Style (CPS) Monad.

I'm using a Type Class based Monad defintion from https://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/AUGER_Monad:

```
Class Monad (m: Type -> Type): Type :=
  {
    return_ {A}:     A -> m A;
    bind    {A B}:   m A -> (A -> m B) -> m B;

    right_unit {A}:  forall (a: m A), bind a return_ = a;
    left_unit  {A}:  forall (a: A) B (f: A -> m B),
                       bind (return_ a) f = f a;
    associativity {A B C}:
                     forall a (f: A -> m B) (g: B -> m C),
                       bind a (fun x => bind (f x) g) = bind (bind a f) g
}.

Notation "a >>= f" := (bind a f) (at level 50, left associativity).
```

The CPS type constructor is from Ralf Hinze's [Functional Pearl](https://wiki.haskell.org/Research_papers/Functional_pearls) about [Compile-time parsing](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ralf.hinze/publications/Quote.pdf) in Haskell

```
Definition CPS (S:Type) := forall A, (S->A) -> A.
```

I defined `bind` and `return_` like this

```
Instance CPSMonad : Monad CPS  :=
  {|
    return_ := fun {A} a {B} => fun (f:A->B) => f a ;
    bind A B := fun (m:CPS A) (k: A -> CPS B)
      =>(fun C => (m _ (fun a => k a _))) : CPS B

  |}.
```

but I'm stuck with the proof obligations for `right_unit` and `associativity`.

```
- unfold CPS; intros.
```

gives the obligation for `right_unit`:

```
  A : Type
  a : forall A0 : Type, (A -> A0) -> A0
  ============================
   (fun C : Type => a ((A -> C) -> C) (fun (a0 : A) (f : A -> C) => f a0)) = a
```

Would be very grateful for help!

EDIT:  András Kovács pointed out that eta conversion in the type checker is sufficient, so `intros; apply eq_refl.`, or `reflexivity.` is enough.

Bur first I had to correct my incorrect definition of `bind`. (The invisible argument `c` was on the wrong side of the `)`...

```
Instance CPSMonad : Monad CPS  :=
  {|
    return_ S s A f     := f s ;
    bind    A B m k C c := m _ (fun a => k a _ c)
  |}.
```

Comment: Maybe you could try going straight for `reflexivity`? From Coq 8.5 there's eta conversion for records, so all the laws should be apparent immediately by normalization and eta conversion.

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely correct.  It also works in 8.4.

Comment: @larsr Want to answer your own question and accept it so this isn't marked "unanswered"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, as mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937980/proving-the-continuation-passing-style-monad-in-coq/40586520#comment59536459_35937980) by [András Kovács](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068232/andr%C3%A1s-kov%C3%A1cs) on Mar 11 at 12:26, is

> Maybe you could try going straight for reflexivity? From Coq 8.5 there's eta conversion for records, so all the laws should be apparent immediately by normalization and eta conversion.

That gives us the following instance:

```
Instance CPSMonad : Monad CPS  :=
  {|
    return_       S s A f :=     f s ;
    bind          A B m k C c := m _ (fun a => k a _ c) ;
    right_unit    A a :=         eq_refl ;
    left_unit     A a B f :=     eq_refl ;
    associativity A B C a f g := eq_refl
  |}.
```